# Upload Custom Workflow Site Action

Tags: workflow, custom-actions, workflow-activity

As a Site Owner is it possible to create a custom workflow action and upload it to SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create custom action.

Follow this article : http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/01/spd-2010-custom-workflow-activity/

Comment: This looks like you need to have access to the Site Collection to upload the workflow.